# non ASCII filenames on GCP persistantvolume not displaying correctly

Tags: linux, kubernetes, filesystems, nfs, google-cloud-filestore

I am moving our .net core(2.1) API from IIS to linux containers in kubernetes in GCP and am having some trouble with files being retrieved from the mounted fileserver when the filenames contain non ASCII characters. Similar to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/513), but these are standard UTF8 characters. åäö

```cs
var di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
if (di.Exists)
{
    var dFiles = di.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    Log.Information($"Files found in {di.Name} : {string.Join(",", dFiles.Select(f => f.Name))}");
    //Log.Information($"Length of files found in {di.Name} : {string.Join(",", dFiles.Select(f => f.Length))}");
    files.AddRange(dFiles);
}
```

`bost�der.pdf` is returned, but it should be `bostäder.pdf`.

In all other cases, characters are handled correctly, such as reading from the database. It is only when reading filenames that there is a problem. I get a `FileNotFoundException` when attempting to read the length of these files. LastWriteTime returns 1601-01-01.

The file is in GCP filestore and mounted to the kubernetes cluster using a PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim and then mounted to the containers.

I have tried to alter the currentthread culture when running this method, but with no luck. The same code works fine on the windows/IIS version using symlinks to point to the fileshare.

If I give the path of the file directly using new FileInfo rather than `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` then the resulting FileInfo object returns the correctly encoded filename although the `FileInfo.Length` method still causes a `FileNotFoundException`.

Have used multiple Docker images

- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-bionic
- mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-stretch-slim

Have also attempted to set the

```
ENV LC_ALL=sv_SE.UTF-8 \
    LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
```

in the Dockerfile with no luck. Any ideas what else I can try?

Edit:

I have now investigated further and the problem is not with .net, but with the mounted drive on the pods. Local files are shown correctly using ls, but the files on the mount are not. So it appears to be something to do with the way the drive is mounted.
I have a persistantvolume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: fileserver
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1T
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    path: /mymount
    server: 1.2.3.4
```

and a persistantvolumeclaim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: fileserver-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1T
```

which is mounted to my pods using

```
volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /mnt/fileserver
            name: pvc
```

and

```
volumes:
      - name: pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: fileserver-claim
          readOnly: false
```

in my deployment.yaml

Edit 2:

Seems to be a problem with Cloud Filestore only supporting NFSv3 - is there any way that I could read these files using NFSv3

Comment: I believe the `a` with the umlaut is extended ASCII, not ASCII. ASCII usually means 8-bit clean. It sounds like you need to select a different code page.

Comment: I tried to create some files on a mounted filestore of my own, and I am able to use the `ä` and other characters, could you share how the files were named of created?